# Unity: Is there any way for a button to call a function of all clones?

Tags: unity, c#, instancing

I really don't know off hand. I've got a few ideas but I'm not at my PC to test it.

like ButtonisPressed > Clone script etc()

```
//on every gameobject clone
void etc() {
  i = 2;
}
```

That way all i's in the clones will be 2. I want it to work like pacman, if all the clones(or ghosts) have i = 2 then they enter their blue state and they change colors. Except I want to call etc() function with a button
Thanks in advance. If no one figures it out, I will report back later (~12hrs)

Comment: There are several approaches to this. But you might get a much more helpful answer if you would tell us why exactly you want to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `FindObjectsOfType` ? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

Comment: Ah, good thought @Philipp. I changed my question to reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something where you would use the Controller pattern.

1. Create a script `GhostController` which has:

   - A `GameObject[] ghosts` to hold the game objects which
   - A public method `CreateGhost` which instantiates a new ghost and adds it to the `ghosts`-array
   - A public method `ChangeGhostState` which calls the function on all game-objects in the `ghosts` array.
2. Put this script into any persistent game object in your scene. A common way to handle this is having some invisible game object which holds all such controller-scripts.
3. Bind the event-handlers of your buttons to these two methods.